# Mongoose return promise out of pre save function

Tags: mongoose, es6-promise, mongoose-schema

I want to ask you about this code:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function userPreSave(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
            .then((hash) => {
                user.password = hash;
                return next();
            })
            .catch(err => next(err));
    }
    return next();
});
```

Can you see any problem or blocking stuff in this code? Specially about this part: `return bcrypt.hash` is it fine to return promise out of it? Won't it have any side effects?